# Splitting an array into 2 arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

**Edit: I have tried the Take/Skip method but I get the following error:**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to   
'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

**I do not know what I am doing wrong because I copied Saeed's code.**

I have a string array (containing anywhere from 20 to 300 items) and I want to split it into 2 separate arrays, from the middle of the first one.

I know how I can do this using a for loop but I would like to know if there was a faster/better way of doing it. I also need to be able to correctly split an array even if it has an odd number of items, eg:

```
string[] words = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "pear", "lemon"};
string[] firstarray, secondarray;
SplitArray(words, out firstarray, out secondarray); // Or some other function
// firstarray has the first 3 of the items from words, 'apple', 'orange' and 'banana'
// secondarray has the other 2, 'pear' and 'lemon'
```

Comment: In order to solve your cast problem add `.ToArray()` after the Take and skip methods

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use linq:

```
firstArray = array.Take(array.Length / 2).ToArray();
secondArray = array.Skip(array.Length / 2).ToArray();
```

Why this works, despite the parity of the original array size?

The firstArray takes `array.Length / 2` elements, and the second one skips the first `array.Length / 2` elements, it means there isn't any conflict between these two arrays. Of course if the number of elements is odd we cannot split the array into two equal size parts.

If you want to have more elements in the first half (in the odd case), do this:

```
firstArray = array.Take((array.Length + 1) / 2).ToArray();
secondArray = array.Skip((array.Length + 1) / 2).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this soon but will this handle the splitting correctly even if it has an odd number of items?

Comment: @Saaed: It doesn't match the stated requirements. Given the example data, `firstArray` will contain `{"apple","orange"}` and `secondArray` will contain `{"banana","pear","lemon"}`. Matthew stated that the first array should be the longer of the two; whether that's really a problem is up to him!

Comment: @LukeH, Thanks, I didn't read his comments, I updated the answer according to your note. (Also I'm Saeed, not Saaed :)

Comment: @LukeH It doesn't really matter which array (firstarray or secondarray) has the extra one item but thanks for the comment!

Comment: You've said `"faster/better"`, so I benchmarked this against a method using 2 `for` loops. Over a million interations this answer takes 613.11 ns, the for loops method takes 77.21ns. If execution time is important, use a lower level approach, otherwise, Linq seems better as it's simpler to maintain.

Comment: @StuperUser, Where I said this is a faster method? OP asked for another way and I answered with most straightforward and simplest way. Sure for loop is faster than this (but `better` is depend to development team).

Comment: The "You" in my comment meant @MatthewRz, the OP. "faster/better" is in his question.

Comment: @StuperUser, Oh :) so use `@` to address someone else :) Also in my opinion this is a better way than using for loops, it uses built-in functions and makes code more readable. (bit optimizations are not welcome compare to readability).

Comment: Yeah, I got confused, I thought that OPs got notified to answer comment threads they had participated in automatically, will included @ mentions for legibility in future too. I agree with you, Take/Skip is a far better solution, if execution speed is not to take priority.

Comment: @StuperUser I am only going to need to split 1 array into 2, so I will use the Take/Skip method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @saeed +1 4 being my friend and colleague + useful answer ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
string[] words = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "pear", "lemon"};
int mid = words.Length/2;
string[] first = words.Take(mid).ToArray();
string[] second = words.Skip(mid).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to/can't use LINQ you can simply do:

```
    string[] words = { "apple", "orange", "banana", "pear", "lemon" };
    string[] firstarray, secondarray;
    int mid = words.Length / 2;
    firstarray = new string[mid];
    secondarray = new string[words.Length - mid];
    Array.Copy(words, 0, firstarray, 0, mid);
    Array.Copy(words, mid, secondarray, 0, secondarray.Length);
```

Answer (score 4):

A more generalized approach that will split it into as many parts as you specify:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int parts)
        {
          return list.Select((item, index) => new {index, item})
                       .GroupBy(x => (x.index + 1) / (list.Count()/parts) + 1)
                       .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.item));
        }
```

*Edited Thanks skarmats

Comment: This will change the order of things. So the nth resulting array will not correspond to the nth section of the source.

Comment: Updated to prevent striping the array.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] words = { "apple", "orange", "banana", "pear", "lemon" };
var halfWay = words.Length/2;

var firstHalf = words.Take(halfWay);
var secondHalf = words.Skip(halfWay);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achive that quite easily using range notation:

```
var x = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
var pivot = x.Length / 2;
var p1 = x[..pivot];
var p2 = x[pivot..];
```

Answer (score -2):

Just in case someone wants to use a function instead:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] ar = { "apple", "orange", "banana", "pear", "lemon" };

        int half =  ar.Length / 2;

        //  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', Split(ar,0, half)));

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', Split(ar,half, ar.Length)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static IEnumerable<T> Split<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int start, int end)
    {
        return items.Skip(start).Take(end);
    }
```

Comment: You've taken the easy to understand `Skip` and `Take` operators and replaced them with a not easy to understand `SplitArray` function that is restricted to working on only arrays (versus `IEnumerable<T>`) and you've introduced `start` and `end` parameters that don't have a clear meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I actually spent time to test it and it worked with strings and integers and I guess, it would for other types. Now, coming to start and end, I have to disagree that start and end are hard to understand. Basically, you wanna split an array but where do you wanna start this splitting and where you wanna end it. That's why I think it's easy to understand. I appreciate your comment and would like to learn from you if you have any concern or comment on what I've mentioned. :)

Comment: Updated the function to make it work with IEnumerable<T> instead of only arrays.